# Middleware Function That Checks If User Is Authenticated

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have an Express middleware function that is checking if the user is authenticated. If they are not authenticated, I want to send some JSON to my frontend that says this, but if they are, I want to continue with my normal function at this route.

For example,

```
const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!authenticated){
        res.status(401).send("You are not authorized to view this content");
    }
    next();
}


app.get('/protectedRoute', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    // SOME OTHER DATABASE STUFF HERE WHICH RESULTS IN VARIABLE "data"
    res.json({msg: data});
});
```

However, I get this error, when trying to return the json:

`Cannot set headers after they are sent to client`

How would I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the request when you detect the request is not authenticated.

Add `return` keyword in `if true` block

```
const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!authenticated){
        return res.status(401).send("You are not authorized to view this content");
    }
    next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're executing `next()` even when the user fails authentication check. This causes you to execute additional code after sending the `401` response which is what the error is complaining about.

Just add an `else`:

```
const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!authenticated){
        res.status(401).send("You are not authorized to view this content");
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
}
```

alternatively, some people prefer to use `return` to break the flow:

```
    if (!authenticated){
        res.status(401).send("You are not authorized to view this content");
        return;
    }
    next();
```